# Express - Using multi-nested routers

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

## The Requirement

I want to create this API hierarchy:

- /api

  - /v1

    - GET /user
  - /v2

    - GET /user

With a matching file structure (e.g. I have an *api* folder, a *v1* folder, a *v2* folder, and a *user.ts* file in each *v1* and *v2* folder that both export an Express router, like so:

```
import { Router } from 'express';

const userRouter = Router();

userRouter.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    // ...
});

export default userRouter;
```

Likewise, in each *v1* and *v2* folder I have a *v1.ts* and *v2.ts* file, respectively, like so:

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import userRouter from './user';

const v1Router = Router(); // v2Router in the other file

v1Router.use('/v1', userRouter); // '/v2' in the other file

export default v1Router; // v2Router in the other file
```

Finally, in the root *api* folder, I have *api.ts* which acts as the primary router for the entire server:

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import v1Router from './v1';
import v2Router from './v2';

const apiRouter = Router();

apiRouter.use('/v1', v1Router);
apiRouter.use('/v2', v2Router);

export default apiRouter;
```

---

## The Problem

None of the routes listed above are available. I should be able to send the following requests:

- GET /api/v1/user
- GET /api/v2/user

However, neither are not found.

When I check the app router stack (by accessing `app._router.stack`), it shows nothing, meaning Express did not recognize the nested routes within the sub-routers. So far, the only workaround is to manually add the user routers directly to the app, which is what I want to avoid to prevent clutter on the main *server.ts* file (for large APIs, imagine having 100+ lines of `app.use(...)` **per** API version all in the main file).

## The Question

Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible? And if so, am I implementing it incorrectly, which is why it's not working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you show this:

```
apiRouter.use('/v1', v1Router);
```

Then, if we look down into `v1Router`, you show this:

```
v1Router.use('/v1', userRouter);
```

Since you've specified `/v1` at two different levels of your router hierarchy, this will represent routes for `/v1/v1` or perhaps some prefix on top of it depending upon how `apiRouter` is registered.

Instead, you should remove the `/v1` prefix from one of those two levels.

---

Separately, you don't show any code where `apiRouter` is hooked up to your Express instance.  This code should exist somewhere where you import `apiRouter`:

```
app.use('/api', apiRouter);
```

Then, you can fix the above issue by just doing this:

```
apiRouter.use('/v1', v1Router);
v1Router.use(userRouter);
```

This will allow `userRouter` to create routes with a prefix of `/api/v1` as in:

```
userRouter.get('/hello', ...);
```

which will respond to `/api/v1/hello`.